# pylint and autoep8 can't be installed

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

New to python and trying to set it up on my local machine.I am trying to install pylint and autopep8 (as per vs code's pop up suggestion) but when i click install i am met with the following error:

```
PS D:\Practice\PythonAutomation> & "D:/Visual Studio/Python37_64/python.exe" c:\Users\Andy stav\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.4.76186\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py pip install -U pylint --user
D:\Visual Studio\Python37_64\python.exe: can't open file 'c:\Users\Andy': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
PS D:\Practice\PythonAutomation> & "D:/Visual Studio/Python37_64/python.exe" c:\Users\Andy stav \.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.4.76186\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py pip install -U autopep8 --user
D:\Visual Studio\Python37_64\python.exe: can't open file 'c:\Users\Andy': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
PS D:\Practice\PythonAutomation>
```

not sure why this is happening? can any one offer any advice?

Andy

Comment: looks like it's mad that there's spaces in your username :(

Comment: bizarre! how do i fix that? or perhaps i should use another IDE?

Comment: can probably send a patch to the extension author I would imagine

Comment: im not sure what you mean? to what extension requires a patch? I thought this was an issue with vs code?

Comment: the extension is open source, you can report a bug here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python

Comment: ahh you mean the python extension that allows it to run on vscode?

thats annoying, i really wanted to get down with python. can you recommend another IDE?

Comment: unfortunately I can't, haven't really used one in a very long time (and if you're just starting out, I'd strongly recommend using an IDE) -- I use a crappy text editor I wrote called `babi`

Comment: Thanks for your help in this, im really surprised there isn't more around this. Surely more people would have this issue. Im sure it's a fairly common naming convention amoung personal pcs

Comment: yeah :( I suspect a vast majority of the devs are on linux or macos where spaces in directory names is much less common

Comment: i decided to opt for Pycharm instead. works perfectly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you ran into a bug that just showed up in the last release. We are tracking it at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/11449.

Answer (score 3):

To be able to install `autopep8` after the VSCode suggestion, I had to run the command manually changing backslashes (`\`) to slashes (`/`).

My terminal uses the `Git Bash` shell and remember that your paths are probably different.

Before:

```
c:/Users/.../.pyenv/pyenv-win/versions/3.8.2/python.exe c:\Users\...\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.3.658691958\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py pip install -U autopep8 --user
```

After:

```
c:/Users/.../.pyenv/pyenv-win/versions/3.8.2/python.exe  c:/Users/.../.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.3.658691958/pythonFiles/pyvsc-run-isolated.py pip install -U autopep8 --user
```

Answer (score 2):

You can solve it by adding extra backslashes. Notice how spaces were automatically added for "Andystav" in your example.

```
D:/Visual Studio/Python37_64/python.exe" c:\\Users\\Andystav\\.vscode\\extensions\\ms-python.python-2020.4.76186\\pythonFiles\\pyvsc-run-isolated.py pip install -U pylint --user
```

> **NB**: Here we are running `pyvsc-run-isolated.py` by giving the full path. In that full path the folder name `ms-python.python-2020.4.76186` always differ. So remember to change that.